# fullcalendar dayClick and selectable conflict

Tags: fullcalendar

An issue i faced while using the select was:
When I click on the date in the month view, the function as specified in the select: function(start, end, allDay) {etc code i want to run here } is immediately fired before changing the view.

I am trying to achieve the following:
1) User clicks on a date on the month view
2) user gets sent to the agendaDay view on the date that he clicked via dayclick() and changeView and gotoDate.
3) User uses select to select time slots.
4) fire up the code i want to run.

Any advice is much sppreciated.

Regards,
Han

Answer (score 3, accepted):

version 1.4.7 added support for a "View Option Hash" for the selectable option, so something like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   selectable: {
      month: false,
      agenda: true
   }
});
```